# How to use license of gantt-chart library from smarthtmlelements

Tags: angular, npm, gantt-chart, htmlelements

Given that I have the license key for gantt-chart library by HTMLELEMENTS. I want to use that license to my project but there is no clear way found on the official docs.

https://www.htmlelements.com/forums/topic/npm-installation-with-license-key/
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHZIj.png)
by using above it shows error in console

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLd3b.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QppNk.png)

I tried using the way they mentioned in the forum but not helpful.

Comment: Maybe you could share more details about the project you are working on like, how the library is included ? Is there any bundler ? etc…